# Multiple Include and Where Clauses Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a database where I'm wanting to return a list of Clients.

These clients have a list of FamilyNames.

I started with this

```
var query = DbContext.Clients.Include(c => c.FamilyNames).ToList() //returns all clients, including their FamilyNames...Great.
```

But I want somebody to be able to search for a FamilyName, ifany results are returned, then show the clients to the user.

so I did this...

```
var query = DbContext.Clients.Include(c => c.FamilyNames.Where(fn => fn.familyName == textEnteredByUser)).ToList();
```

I tried...

```
var query = DbContext.Clients.Include(c => c.FamilyNames.Any(fn => fn.familyName == textEnteredByUser)).ToList();
```

and...

```
var query = DbContext.FamilyNames.Include(c => c.Clients).where(fn => fn.familyname == textEnteredByUser.Select(c => c.Clients)).ToList();
```

What I would like to know (obviously!) is how I could get this to work, but I would like it if at all possible to be done in one query to the database. Even if somebody can point me in the correct direction.

Kind regards

Comment: query get executed ? or there are some errors or exceptions at run time ?

I had problem with nested IQueryable query, and solution was to cast .AsEnumerable, and take some data to memody, during operation.
Please write some details, maybe I'll remind sth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linq to Entities you can navigate on properties and they will be transformed to join statements.

This will return a list of clients.

```
var query = DbContext.Clients.Where(c => c.FamilyNames.Any(fn => fn == textEnteredByUser)).ToList();
```

If you want to include all their family names with eager loading, this should work:

```
var query = DbContext.Clients.Where(c => c.FamilyNames.Any(fn => fn == textEnteredByUser)).Include(c => c.FamilyNames).ToList();
```

Here is some reference about [loading related entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) if something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick to answer. It works, but what I wanted to include was the clients, including their FamilyNames. Thank you

Comment: I think this should work acording to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx:    DbContext.Clients.Where(c => c.FamilyNames.Any(fn => fn == textEnteredByUser)).Include(c => c.FamilyNames).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Projection', basically you select just the fields you want from any level into a new object, possibly anonymous.

```
var query = DbContext.Clients
    .Where(c => c.FamilyNames.Any(fn => fn == textEnteredByUser))
    // only calls that can be converted to SQL safely here
    .Select(c => new {
        ClientName = c.Name,
        FamilyNames = c.FamilyNames
    })
    // force the query to be materialized so we can safely do other transforms
    .ToList()
    // convert the anon class to what we need
    .Select(anon => new ClientViewModel() {
        ClientName = anon.ClientName,
        // convert IEnumerable<string> to List<string>
        FamilyNames = anon.FamilyNames.ToList()
    });
```

That creates an anonymous class with just those two properties, then forces the query to run, then performs a 2nd projection into a ViewModel class.

Usually I would be selecting into a ViewModel for passing to the UI, limiting it to just the bare minimum number of fields that the UI needs. Your needs may vary.

Comment: I think this will fail. ToList() can't be transformed to a query by linq to entities.

Comment: @Cosmin yes, sorry I was doing it off-the-top-of-my-head, in my code I often have to project twice, once with DB-safe calls and a 2nd time with anything that isn't DB-safe (like formatting, calling other methods to transform, etc). I will update my answer.